# Is it possible to call numba jited function from C/C++?

Tags: python, c++, c, numba

I would like to interface C++ library in python which takes function pointer as argument. I look that it is possible to make call in C with `PyEval_CallObject`, but to proceed it further I need correct signature (types of input and output arguments). Is it possible to return callback from python with specified signature?

Also I am a bit performance woried, so I also have looked on python `numba` project which does compilation of python function. I am quite interested if it can be accessed in C/C++ so to improve performance.

Comment: Recent versions of numba give the function the attributes `inspect_llvm` and `inspect_asm` methods which "Return a dictionary keying compiled function signatures to [either llvm or asm code]". You could call them and get the keys from the dictionary to work out the signatures. If you are using lazy compilation (haven't provided an explicit signature) these won't be of any use.

Comment: (Note that you only get the input types from these though)

Comment: You are very very very unlikely to gain any speed advantage from calling your numba functions from C++ - they still go through most of the standard python calling method, and calling overhead is unlikely to be the main cost.

Comment: but if the function is jitted doesn't it mean that it is compiled to self contained binary? So if I could figure out the filename of binary then with an wise way I would be able to use it in C++ without python between it

Comment: I think they're compiled to memory rather than to a file. I suppose in principle you could use it (if you could find it). I don't think there's a publicly accessible interface to it, and you'd have to work out what calling convention it uses if you could find it (it might not be designed to be C compatible)

Comment: Actually, if you go back far enough in time it looks like it was supported: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.11/interface_c.html#using-numba-functions-in-external-code. I think that was lost in a big refactor around Numba 0.12 though.

Answer (score 4):

Numba's jited function is compiled in-memory, not in file. This function has regular Pythonic interface, which is a thin wrapper that converts Python arguments to C types and calls jited machine code as regular C/Assembler function.

Numba compiles (jits) function on the fly and on-demand, meaning that it compiles on very first call. Also Numba precompiles function with different arguments types, i.e. if you pass one type Numba compiles one instance of machine code, if you pass another type as argument Numba compiles another instance. Compiled code is cached, same types of arguments on second call use cached version of machine code.

Numba's functions are regular Pythonic functions. But Numba is very friendly to [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) library, so it supports conversion to ctypes' `CFUNCTYPE` which allows access directly to machine code with given fixed C types of arguments.

In order to specify just one type of arguments you have to write something like

```
@numba.njit(numba.int64(numba.int64, numba.int64))
```

i.e. pass fixed types of arguments to `@njit` decorator.

BTW, you can use `@jit` (less optimized, but can accept almost any Python code), or `@njit` (more optimized, but needs strict rules for code writing).

Below I created example of C++ code for you, which calls Numba's jited function from C++. I showed how to call it in three ways - 1) as C function using `ctypes` wrapper. 2) as Python function using [PyObject_Call()](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/call.html#c.PyObject_Call). 3) through `@numba.cfunc` decorator and `.address` property, read about it [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/cfunc.html) (3rd suggested by @max9111).

If you need speed and smallest CALL overhead when having just C types then choose solution with `@cfunc`, it is the most efficient (fastest) solution (also shortest to implement), according to @max9111. Basically `.address` property just gives direct address of C function's machine code without any overhead and preparation. Use `pyfunc` method if you have Python objects as arguments and/or you want to pass objects of different Python types and/or if you have `@jit` (not `@njit`) and/or you don't care about speed.

**Important Note!!!** My code doesn't cleanup anything, you should delete all created references to all objects through [Py_XDECREF()](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/refcounting.html#c.Py_XDECREF). Also I might be doing not all error checking, you have to error-check every Python C API function that may return error. I did this two simplifications to make code shorter and more understandable, just to show main points of example.

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow32221418#main.cpp)

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

#include <Python.h>

#define ASSERT(cond) { if (!(cond)) throw std::runtime_error( \
    "Assertion (" #cond ") failed at line " + std::to_string(__LINE__) + "!"); }
#define CH(cond) [&]{ auto r = (cond); if (PyErr_Occurred()) { PyErr_Print(); std::cerr << std::flush; \
    throw std::runtime_error("PyAssertion (" #cond ") failed at line " + std::to_string(__LINE__) + "!"); } return r; }()

int main() {
    try {
        std::cout << "Wait..." << std::endl;
        Py_Initialize();
        auto globals = CH(PyDict_New()), locals = CH(PyDict_New());
        CH(PyRun_String(R"(
import numba as nb, ctypes

@nb.njit(nb.int64(nb.int64, nb.int64))
def mul1(a, b):
    return a * b

@nb.cfunc(nb.int64(nb.int64, nb.int64))
def mul2(a, b):
    return a * b

cmul1 = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(
    ctypes.c_int64, ctypes.c_int64, ctypes.c_int64)(mul1)
addr1 = ctypes.cast(cmul1, ctypes.c_void_p).value
addr2 = mul2.address
        )", Py_file_input, globals, locals));
        //std::cout << CH(PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(CH(PyObject_Str(locals)), nullptr)) << std::endl;
        auto cfunc1 = (int64_t (*)(int64_t, int64_t))
            CH(PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong(CH(PyDict_GetItemString(locals, "addr1"))));
        auto cfunc2 = (int64_t (*)(int64_t, int64_t))
            CH(PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong(CH(PyDict_GetItemString(locals, "addr2"))));
        std::cout << "pyfunc: 3 * 5 = " << CH(PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(
            CH(PyObject_Str(CH(PyObject_Call(
                CH(PyDict_GetItemString(locals, "mul1")), PyTuple_Pack(
                    2, PyLong_FromLongLong(3), PyLong_FromLongLong(5)), nullptr /* named args */
            )))), nullptr)) << std::endl << std::flush;
        std::cout << "cfunc1 (0x" << std::hex << uint64_t(cfunc1) << std::dec
            << "): 3 * 5 = " << cfunc1(3, 5) << std::endl << std::flush;
        std::cout << "cfunc2 (0x" << std::hex << uint64_t(cfunc2) << std::dec
            << "): 3 * 5 = " << cfunc2(3, 5) << std::endl << std::flush;
        ASSERT(Py_FinalizeEx() == 0);
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl << std::flush;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Wait...
pyfunc: 3 * 5 = 15
cfunc1 (0x7f5db072f080): 3 * 5 = 15
cfunc2 (0x7f5db05b2010): 3 * 5 = 15
```

Comment: Also a possible way would be to call a Python function which hands over a function pointer to a numba cfunc https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/cfunc.html After this you can work with this function pointer in the same way as with other C/C++ function pointers (the call overhead is also the same if this is important).

Comment: @max9111 Thanks! I'll try to implement now what you suggested, as one more example of usage. Can you also tell if my solution with wrapping into `CFUNCTYPE` has any overhead? I mean if a call from C++ goes directly to compiled machine code of a function, or it has some extra layer that does some preparation?

Comment: I am not sure about this, but I guess your solution is equivalent to passing a njit function to for example https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html#scipy.integrate.quad This is quite a lot slower (but less work) than using the low-level-callable (a function pointer directly pointing to compiled code without any Interpreter interaction). https://stackoverflow.com/q/58421549/4045774 This example would be a lot simpler without the burden to pass additional arrays through the interface.

Comment: @max9111 Implemented and posted your `@cfunc` solution as 3rd way of doing things.